# dir(object) vs object.__dir__()

Tags: python, class

Here is the simple Python code: What's the difference between Case 1 and Case 2 -- why am I getting result as False in first case and True in other? Why are the `id`s equal in the Case 2? Also does `dir(object)` call `object._dir__()` internally? If so the return object/results of two calls should it be the same.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = "a1"


hello = Hello()
print(hello)

# Case 1
var1 = dir(hello)
var2 = hello.__dir__()
print(id(var1), id(var2), id(var1) == id(var2))

# Case 2
print(id(dir(hello)), id(hello.__dir__()), id(dir(hello)) == id(hello.__dir__()))
print(dir(hello) == hello.__dir__())
```

**Output**

```
<__main__.Hello object at 0x7f320828c320>
139852862206472 139852862013960 False
139852862014024 139852862014024 True
False
```

Comment: If you don't think your question is a duplicate, add a comment explaining why. And if the answers (either to the original question, or to this one) don't cover everything you wanted to know, add a comment. Just editing your question repeatedly and hoping we'll notice the changes only works if you get really lucky with the timing.

Comment: @abarnert, I'm very new to stackoverflow. I'll do it from next time, Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't have said anything, except that I happened to notice one of your edits just as I was about to close the page, and answered it by editing my answer, and I didn't want to give the false impression that you can count on that kind of timing every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a coincidence that you're ever getting `True`. (Well, not a *coincidence*, since the implementation of CPython makes it very likely… but it's not something the language requires.)

In case 1, you have two different `dict`s in `var1` and `var2`. They're both alive at the same time, so they can't have the same `id`.

In case 2, you again have two different `dict`s—but this time, you aren't storing them anywhere; as soon as you call `id` on one, you release it, which means it can get garbage collected<sup>*</sup> before you get the other one,<sup>**</sup> which means it can end up reusing the same `id`.<sup>***</sup>

Notice that the docs for [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) say:

> This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

If you actually want to test whether two expressions refer to the same object, use `is`, don't compare their `id`s.

---

Your edited question also asks:

> Also does dir(object) calls object._dir__() internally?

According to [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of attributes.

And the data model section on [`__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) says:

> Called when `dir()` is called on the object. A sequence must be returned. `dir()` converts the returned sequence to a list and sorts it.

Then you say:

> If so the return object of two calls should be the same.

Well, it depends on what you mean by "the same". It should return *an equal* value (since nothing has changed), but it's not going to be *the identical* value, which is what you're trying to test for. (If it isn't obvious why `dir` gives you a new list each time, it should still be clear that it *must* do so from the fact that "`dir()` converts the returned sequence to a list and sorts it"…)

---

<sub>* Because CPython uses reference counting as its primary garbage collection mechanism, "can be collected" generally means "will be collected immediately". This isn't true for most other Python implementations.</sub>

<sub>** If the order in which parts of your expression get evaluated isn't clear to you from reading the docs, you can try `dis.dis('id(dir(hello)) == id(hello.__dir__())')` to see the actual bytecodes in order.</sub>

<sub>*** In CPython, the `id` is just the address of the `PyObject` struct that represents the object; if one `PyObject` gets freed and another one of the same type gets allocated immediately after, it will usually get the same address.</sub>

Comment: Having same id for dir(object) and object._dir__() is what confused me, Now it's clear. Thanks.

Also if dir(object) calls object.__dir__(), why the call to __dir__() is it not showing up in disassembler code?  

dis.dis('dir(hello)')